# Multiple Cores vs Single Core Power Efficiency Equations

Tags: efficiency, cpu

I was searching for OpenMP tutorials and I came up a video that showed some simple equations that promotes multiple core hierarchies against single core ones. 
The equations used are

> Capacitance = Ability to store energy
>
> C=q/V ⇒ q=CV
>
> Work = Moving charge across voltage
>
> W=Vq ⇒ W=CV^2
>
> Power = Work over a period of time
>
> P=Wf ⇒ P=CV^2f

[image]

It then proceeds to calculate power requirement of a single core processor as

> Ps = CsVs^2fs

where Xs stands for X used on single core system.

[image]
It then goes on to calculate it for a dual core system responsible for doing the same work. But it uses following parameters (Not exactly 2 or 0.5 multipliers but they just make the problem more easier to understand):

> Cd = 2Cs 
>   Vd = 0.5Vs
>   fd = 0.5fs

Power is calculated as

> Pd = 0.25Ps

I don't get why voltage and capacitance are altered.

The video is over here youtu.be/cMWGeJyrc9w?t=3m45s, if time link doesn't work for you. It starts about 3:45.

Comment: I think any question about voltages and capacitances is two low-level for computer science. We assume that the zeroes and ones just work; making them happen is for electrical engineers.

Comment: As I have come up to these diagrams on a computer science course I thought this might be relevant

Comment: When the transistors do not have to switch as fast (reduced frequency) the voltage can be reduced (this is called dynamic voltage frequency scaling), though the voltage range is constrained and transistor speed is not the only determiner of frequency. Approximating capacitance *per core* as constant is somewhat reasonable. Even better energy efficiency can be achieved if the cores are designed for lower performance. This really is more of an EE question.